# Safecracker Registration - Custom Confirmation Page

Tags: safecracker-registration

Is there a way to customize or replace the account confirmation page?

I want the page to align with the design philosophy of the site. So I want it to look close to the other pages I have.

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using Safecracker Registration you can avoid the ugly default User Message Templates altogether if you set a `return` parameter. As an example:

```
{exp:safecracker
    channel="members"
    dynamic_title="[member_first_name] [member_last_name] - [email]"
    include_jquery="no"
    register_member="yes"
    error_handling="inline"
    return="/some/url/path"
}
```

This way you can specify where the user will be sent for account confirmation using regular EE templates rather than standard User Message Templates.

---

**EDIT: Updated to include options for editing EE's User Message Templates**

Most actions performed in EE, such as logging in/out, safecracker submission etc, will result in seeing the User Message Template in EE. This can be modified by navigating to

Design > Message Pages > User Messages

The control here is fairly limited in that it's one message template which applies to ALL system messages. It's also not possible to parse other template tags but at a basic level it does the job.

If you want a little more control over your *User Message Templates* and *Speciality Templates* in general however then you could look to use either [Custom System Messages](http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/custom-system-messages) or [Libraree](http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/libraree) to bring bring them into regular EE templates which can be saved as files. As regular EE templates you'll also have the ability to then use other tags along with embeds to keep things DRY. It all depends on how much control you need.

Comment: I think the return parameter only pertains to the page immediately after registering. I am talking about the page that is in the link in the confirmation email, the one with an ACT param

Comment: In that case those are back over in EE's default message handling. I've updated my answer to include editing of those message pages and options available.

Comment: Thanks for the assist Ian! If you anyone has any more questions feel free to email support@objectivehtml.com.